# SQL - counter based on condition

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Given the `Date` and `Type` columns, I want to create the column `Group` like in the table below where a `Type` of "A" marks the beginning of each group

| Date | Type | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-09-26 | A | 1 |
| 2019-09-26 | B | 1 |
| 2019-10-09 | B | 1 |
| 2020-08-18 | A | 2 |
| 2020-09-25 | B | 2 |
| 2020-09-27 | B | 2 |
| 2021-02-19 | B | 2 |
| 2021-07-04 | A | 3 |
| 2021-08-04 | B | 3 |
| 2022-03-17 | A | 4 |
| 2022-05-01 | B | 4 |
| 2022-05-05 | B | 4 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional_true_event.html) windowed function:

> Returns a window event number for each row within a window partition based on the result of the boolean argument expr1. The number starts from 0 and is incremented by 1 for each row on which the expr1 evaluates to true.

```
SELECT *, CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(Type='A') OVER(ORDER BY Date) + 1 AS grp
FROM tab
ORDER BY Date;
```